# Extracting component from all objects within an indexed list

Tags: r

I have an indexed list containing several objects each of which contains 3 matrices ($tab, $nobs and $other). There are hundred such objects in the list.  The objective is to access only $tab matrix and transpose it from each of the objects.

```
genfreqT <- lapply(genfreq[[1:100]]$tab, function(x) t(x))
```

This does not seem to work.

Here is how the `genfreq` object is structured.  This was created with R package adegenet.

```
> str(genfreq[[1]])
List of 3
 $ tab : num [1:30, 1:1974] 0.6 0.5 0.325 0.675 0.6 0.5 0.5 0.375 0.55 0.475 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : Named chr [1:30] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:30] "01" "02" "03" "04" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:1974] "L0001.1" "L0001.2" "L0002.1" "L0002.2" ...
 $ nobs: num [1:30, 1:1000] 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : Named chr [1:30] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:30] "01" "02" "03" "04" ...
  .. ..$ : Named chr [1:1000] "L0001" "L0002" "L0003" "L0004" ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:1000] "L0001" "L0002" "L0003" "L0004" ...
 $ call: language makefreq(x = x, truenames = TRUE)
```

Comment: problem is in the [[1:100]] that you use on your list of matrices , a loop will work I guess:    for (i in 1:100) {
lapply(genfreq[[i]]$tab, function(x) t(x))
}   ... but more info on error message that you receive would be welcome to be able to answer

Comment: @jebsel The error I get is: Error in genfreq[[1:100]]$tab : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.
Also, your solution does not produce any errors, but there is nothing in genfreqT after running that for loop.

Comment: How about `lapply(genfreq[1:100], function(x) t(x$tab))`?

Comment: That could have been very clever solution, but unfortunately produces the same atomic vector error as above.  Just to be clear I tried "lapply(genfreq[[1:100]], function(x) t(x$tab))"

Comment: please provide a minimal dataset like yours to be able to reproduce the error, the $ operator is not something you can use on the list data you have

Comment: @jebsel The genfreq is an object from package adegenet.  I can't make any changes to the way this package structures the data.  Also, providing a MWE would be rather difficult here.

Comment: genfreqT <-t(lapply(genfreq, `[[`, "tab"))  does this work?

Comment: Nope. Unexpected '[['

Answer (score 2):

```
genfreqT <-lapply(lapply(genfreq, "[[", "tab"),function(x) t(x))
```

Comment: Yes sir!  That works.  Can you explain what the inner lapply is doing?

Comment: lapply(genfreq, "[[", "tab")  is to extract all matrices ( function [[ ) with name "tab" in the list

Answer (score 0):

The package developer for '`Adegenet`' provided this solution:

```
> genfreqT <- lapply(genfreq, function(e) t(e$tab))

> summary(genfreqT)
                  Length Class  Mode   
data1.str 59220  -none- numeric
data2.str 59220  -none- numeric
data3.str 59220  -none- numeric
```